# Setting up jquery timeago plugin

Tags: php, jquery, timeago

I am trying to setup the jQuery timeago plugin with dates in the PHP format:

```
d/m/Y H:i:s
```

but to little success. Here is what I've done so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});
});
</script>

<abbr class="timeago" title="30/01/2013 13:30:06">30/01/2013 13:30:06</abbr>
```

I've included a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mc8ft/2/

More information about the timeago plugin can be found here: http://timeago.yarp.com/

Comment: There was a syntax error. I fixed it in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mc8ft/3/ , but I don't see a different result, don't know what that plugin does :/

Comment: @davids Thanks, I didn't realise. There's some info on the plugin here: http://timeago.yarp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there was a syntax error (the last `});` is not needed). Secondly, it seems that the plugin does not accept the date in the format you have it in your fiddle, it should be something like `yyyy/mm/dd`.

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/mc8ft/4/

Comment: Ah.. but all the dates in my SQL table are currently in the format d/m/Y H:i:s. Any way I can work around this? :-(

Comment: Either you modify the plugin or modify the format of the date (hint http://stackoverflow.com/a/8040832/978515)

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your script. remove last `});`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! But the plugin still doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: I m not sure but maybe you can also just use class $(".timeago").timeago();