# trim datetime to use only HH:mm.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using datetime picker where I'm getting date in format like

```
2017-02-07 10:05
```

how can I trim this to use only HH:mm.

p.s. I dont want to change date format on datetime picker initialization

Comment: you can just split this string by  " " and get its [1] index ele

Comment: you can use split  method

Comment: Right above the "Ask question" button, there is the search field... http://stackoverflow.com/a/8040818/1151408

Answer (score 1):

Example one:

```
var d = new Date("2017-02-07 10:05");
console.log(d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes());
```

Example two:

```
"2017-02-07 10:05".split(" ")[1]
```

Comment: Please allow this to be closed as duplicate. It is not rocket science - your second example was already commented 5 minutes ago