# Datatable timestamp wrong format

Tags: javascript, jquery, postgresql, datatables

```
2019-11-19 15:35:52.494
```

This is actual data in my database table, but in the datatable I get this:

```
2019-11-19T10:05
```

The date format is wrong.

How can i solve this?

Comment: The format is not wrong, The T is just a standard (ISO 8601) way to delimit the time.

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 0):

> The date format is wrong.

The format is not wrong, The `T` is just a standard ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) way to de-limit the time. 
To remove `T` from your datetime string you could format your string using pure Javascript something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040771/how-to-change-date-format-in-javascript) or you can use any other library like [moment](https://momentjs.com/). Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993913/format-date-with-moment-js) for formatting using moment js.

Answer (score 0):

In `columnDefs`, add your target column

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({

    columnDefs:[{targets:4, render:function(data){
      return moment(data).format('MMMM Do YYYY'); 
    }}]
  });
});
```

In `targets` put your column number and In `format` put the format you want to display. You can try with different format follow this below link

[click here for demo](http://live.datatables.net/ciwumehe/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't necessarily need it to be a date type, you could try to cast the timestamp to text in your select statement when you retrieve it from the database, like this:

> SELECT TO_CHAR(NOW(),'dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss') AS date_time

Here is [more info](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html) about formatting using **TO_CHAR**.